# How to invoke a web service from a stand alone Java client?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I have an echo web service running on lets say `http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/Service1`. This service just echos back a string that is sent to it through the function `echo()`. Using the wsdl of the above mentioned service (Service.wsdl), I have generated (in eclipse) the ServiceStub.java and the ServiceCallbackHandler.java. With these two files, how can I write a client which will invoke `echo(String some_word)` and receive the response back? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Eclipse WTP Tutorials - Creating Bottom Up Web Service via Apache Axis2](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html), starting from step 27.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to test/exercise your web service, I recommend SOAPUI - http://www.soapui.org/

Point it at your WSDL and it will allow you to call your Web Service methods.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:
(see also: [Axis2 Web Service (Tomcat v6)](http://swiss-knife.blogspot.com/2009/12/axis2-web-service-tomcat-v6.html)

```
package com.gg.ws;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;

import com.gg.ws.ServiceStub.Echo;
import com.gg.ws.ServiceStub.EchoResponse;


public class WebServiceTest {

    public void callEcho() throws RemoteException {

        ServiceStub stub = new ServiceStub();

        Echo request = new Echo();
        request.setValue("Whatever");
        EchoResponse response = stub.echo(request);
        System.out.println(" echo call   response: " + response.get_return());
    }
}
```